# how to find text on a result textbox?

Tags: c#

hi everyone i have an c# windows phone 8.1 app i have a result text box, i want to search in the result text box for text that will be print on him after a for loop start that's mean if my result TextBox have the value already i don't want him to print it again and if not print it my app calculate the pythagorean number i don't know how to do it plz help my faild try is :

```
if (from.Text == "0")
    start = start + 1;
for (int i = start; i <= end; i++) {
    for (int j = start+1; j <= end; j++) {
        for (int k = start; k <= end; k++) {
            if (i * i + j * j == k*k) {
                string now = j + "+" + i ;
                result.FindName(now);
                result.Text += Environment.NewLine + (i + " + " + j + " = " + k) + Environment.NewLine;
                c++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

i search in google for it but it look like there's no answer ! plz help me !!!!

Comment: Try `result.Text.Contains(someString)`.

Comment: Textboxes don't even have a method called `FindName()`.

Comment: I need a value like  if (result.Text.contains(new)==true) value=0 else value=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the real answer is this:

```
   result.Text.Contains(someString)
```